# Mesh is not editable in edit mode, but shows properly in object mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertex-groups

[image]

I downloaded this project file, I want to edit this book mesh in *Edit Mode*.

However, when I go into *Edit Mode* it just show the blank mesh with no possibility of editing, while I can see the edges, vertices and loopcuts in object mode.

How so? Is it some vertex group magic? I am not well versed.

[image]

Comment: Your object has been made with geonodes, you need to convert to mesh (applying the modifier doesn't seem to entirely convert to mesh so I guess you need to create a node within the geonode setup)

Comment: Thank you! Thanx for the reply

Comment: To be precise: the upper connection going into the _Join Geometry_ node needs a _Realize Instances_ node plugged in-between. Or you can put it simply between the _Join Geometry_ and the _Group Output_.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 2):

The book is generated using geometry nodes. There is no editable geometry. Switch to the "Geonodes" workspace to see the node tree.

*Perhaps this belongs in a comment ? I'm not sure. I see Moonboots responded in a comment already*

If you want to convert this geonodes book to editable geometry, you need to apply the modifier (ctrl+A in the modifier list). However the object contains instances, and those will be absent in the resulting mesh if you apply it right away. So you need to first enter the nodetree and add a *Realize instances* node at the end (which converts any instance to a proper mesh), only then can you apply it.

In the capture below I am showing the very end of the nodetree with a *Realize instances* node added right before the output. At the top, I've opened a spreadsheet editor to show exactly what the generated object is made of. As you can see, there are 14 instances (they still appear in the list because I temporarily muted the *Realize instances* node).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it

Comment: That's it but maybe explain how to convert to mesh? I think there's a node but I don't know enough about geonodes to answer

Comment: Ah yes, good idea